# In vimperator, how to pass through certain keys on certain sites?

Tags: vimperator

I'd like to set certain keys to be passed-through on certain sites. So, e.g., j/k would be passed through on `*duckduckgo.com*` but work elsewhere.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I switched back to vimperator from pentadactyl (too slow) and I needed this feature. It is provided by the `:ignorekeys` command, like so:

```
:ignorekeys add http://example.com/
```

This will ignore all keys, including `:` and `/` so you might want at least something like:

```
:ignorekeys add -except=:,/ http://example.com/
```

See `:help :ignorekeys` for more!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but for anyone that stumbles across this question.

At the time of writing, 2017-02-15, vimperator have the option "passthrough" that can be toggled by:

:set passthrough
and
:set nopassthrough

This is the same as pentactatyls ^C-v

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it sounds like there's allegedly a plugin for Vimperator that I never found, but It's built into Pentadactyl using the `passkeys` option.

[Documentation here](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/help/pentadactyl/options.xhtml#%27passkeys%27).